# GNUPLOT splot color palete matching jetmap

Tags: colors, gnuplot, surface, colormap, palette

I'm trying to reproduce the following image of rosenbrock  function in gnuplot. Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function).

[image: See below]

My understanding is that the image was created using JET colormap in Matlab/Matplotlib.

Here is my attempt in gnuplot. Macro MATLAB was sourced from [here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/matlab-colorbar-with-gnuplot/) and Macro JET was sourced from [here](http://ayapin-film.sakura.ne.jp/Gnuplot/Primer/Misc/colormap.html).

I think bringing the orange/yellow all the way down to 500 would be helpful. I'm not sure how to do this in gnuplot.

Also what would be the `size` to reproduce `MATLAB` like view?

```
reset session
set terminal wxt size 800,600 enhanced font 'Verdana,10' persist
set view 50,330
set isosample 30
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set zlabel "f(x,y)" rotate
set pm3d


set macros
JET="define (0 0 0 0.5, 1./8 0 0 1, 3./8 0 1 1, 5./8 1 1 0, 7./8 1 0 0, 1 0.5 0 0)"

MATLAB = "defined (0  0.0 0.0 0.5, \
                   1  0.0 0.0 1.0, \
                   2  0.0 0.5 1.0, \
                   3  0.0 1.0 1.0, \
                   4  0.5 1.0 0.5, \
                   5  1.0 1.0 0.0, \
                   6  1.0 0.5 0.0, \
                   7  1.0 0.0 0.0, \
                   8  0.5 0.0 0.0 )"


set palette @JET

splot [x=-2:2] [y=-1:3] (1-x)**2+100*(y-x**2)**2 with pm3d notitle

set output
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**color mapping**

I think you will be most of the way there if you change the color mapping to log scale,
and the rest of the way there if you adjust the lower bound on the palette range:

```
# ... as above ...
set log cb
set cbrange [0.1 : *]
unset mcbtics
replot
```

[image]

**bounding box**

gnuplot version 5.4:

```
set wall x1  fillcolor "gray90"
set wall y1  fillcolor "gray90"
set wall z0  fillcolot "gray50"
set xyplane at 0
set border 127
set grid vertical
replot
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent and Brilliant, thank you very much. Can you please let me know if we could make the gnuplot interms of width (x) and length (y) similar to the original picture. I tried quite a lot but the aspect ratio seems to not working. is `size` the right way to adjust the width and length?

Comment: The command you want is probably `set view 50, 330, <scale_1>, <scale_2>`.  The easiest way to find appropriate values for the two scale parameters is to use click-and-drag with the middle mouse button.  Adjust things to suit your preference and then read the scale values off the toolbar or issue a `show view` command.